# Disable Ripple feedback on Microsoft Surface

Tags: c#, wpf, pixelsense

I'm doing some WPF development on a Microsoft Surface, and I'd like to disable the ripples feedback (the visual animations you get for each contact down, up, move etc). I can't find a way to disable it, is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Yes it's possible - you can disable touch/contact visualizations for any control or surfacewindow by calling

```
ContactVisualizer.SetShowsVisualizations(ctrl, false);
```

or by adding the following attributes to the XAML:

```
xmlns:s="http://schemas.microsoft.com/surface/2008"
s:ContactVisualizer.ShowsVisualizations="False"
```

If you'd like to disable it for the entire application, add the following line to the `appsettings` section of the application's config file:

```
<add key="SupportsContactVisualizations" value="False" />
```

As Robert correctly pointed out, for surface 1.0 you need to use the [`ContactVisualizer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.surface.presentation.controls.contactvisualizations.contactvisualizer%28Surface.10%29.aspx), for WPF 4 the class has been renamed to `TouchVisualizer`. Examples for the second one on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee957377.aspx) can easily be adapted for surface 1.0 by changing *Touch* to *Contact*.

Comment: You need to include the `xmlns:s="http://schemas.microsoft.com/surface/2008"` part, otherwise the `s:` makes no sense.

Comment: This is correct for WPF4.  For Surface 1.0 however, you need to replace the word "Touch" on all of these APIs with "Contact" in order to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Thx Robert, I should have tested... I have now, and I updated the answer.